# Design Calculations & Mathematical Modeling of Tricopters

Tags: design

I have been studying about building a tricopter.  But I couldn't find the design calculations or mathematical modeling of the tricopter any where over the internet.

What are the mathematical relationships or equations of motion and forces in tricopter?  How do I calculate the requirements of the structural design and the energy requirements of the motors?

Answer (score 1):

I found the following paper, [Model Predictive Control of a Tricopter (Barsk, J. 2012)](http://liu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:538067/FULLTEXT01.pdf) quite helpful.

Comment: thanks very much but i already found that and reading but it isn't really meeting my needs .I didn't mean to spam the web i just thought i could get more help

Comment: What i truly need is mathematical relationships or equations of motion and forces in tricopter along with structural design calculations and energy calculations of motots .sounds crazy right ?

Answer (score 1):

I too posted the same question here..:) To calculater the output power required check this link: http://www.wired.com/2014/05/modeling-the-thrust-from-a-quadcopter/

The same power can be applied to tricopter also..